# C# Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double[]' and 'ulong'

Tags: c#, output, operator-keyword

Good day,

as C# newbie i'm facing another problem with C# that in C is not problem at all.

I have this method that calls other methods and looks like this.

```
public double ipoval(double[] xa,double[] ya, int n, double x, int ipord)
{
    ulong ind, jnd;
    double y, dy;
    if (ipord>=1)
    {
        hunt(xa,Convert.ToUInt64(n),x, ind);
        jnd = Math.Min(Math.Max(ind - ipord / 2, 1), n - ipord);
        polint(xa + jnd - 1, ya + jnd - 1, ipord + 1, x, y, dy);
    }
    return y;
}
```

Now it shows me this errors for jnd:

- Error    1   Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ulong' and 'int'
- Error    2   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Math.Max(decimal, decimal)'
- Error    3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'decimal'

Looks like C# have a problem with subtracting two different data types. Should i convert that int ipord into ulong?

And method polint has an error of kinda similar type:

- Error 4  Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double[]' and 'ulong'
- Error 5  Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double[]' and 'ulong'

Any ideas? Thank you in advance for help.

I have same thing in C and it works:

```
NRREAL ipoval(NRREAL xa[], NRREAL ya[], const int n, const NRREAL x, const int ipord)
{
    unsigned long ind,jnd;
    NRREAL y,dy,*y2;
    if (ipord>=1) { /* polynomial interpolation of ipord-th order */
        hunt(xa,(unsigned long)n,x,&ind);
        jnd=IMIN(IMAX(ind-ipord/2,1),n-ipord);
        polint(xa+jnd-1,ya+jnd-1,ipord+1,x,&y,&dy);
    }
    return y;
}
```

Btw little side question, in that polint method in c# with parameters like this:

```
public void polint(double[] xa, double[] ya, int n, double x, ref double y, ref double dy)
```

because i want y,dy as output from that void method.

Sorry for long post and thanks once again.

Comment: You are trying to index an array by adding a number to its base pointer like it is possible in C. You cannot do that in C#

Comment: C# isn't C - just because they have a similar name does not mean that any of their behavior is guaranteed to be the same. You need to understand C# and re-write your code in the way the language intends it to be written, not just try to force some C code to compile in it

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
public double ipoval(double[] xa,double[] ya, int n, double x, int ipord)
{
    ulong ind = 0, jnd = 0;
    double y = 0, dy = 0;
    if (ipord>=1)
    {

        hunt(xa,(ulong)n,x, ind);
        jnd = (ulong)Math.Min(Math.Max(ind - (ulong)ipord / 2, 1), n - ipord);
        polint(xa[jnd - 1], ya[jnd - 1], ipord + 1, x, ref y, ref dy);
    }
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors; first, you must assign an initial value to a variable, whether it be `new ulong()` or a direct value such as `ulong a = 0;`

Next, in the line where you use use `Math.Max(...)` you use a minus operator between an `int` and a `ulong`, this throws another error; when using 2 different numerical types such as the ones above, you most of the time want to cast the one with the smaller range to the one with the larger range because the limit of the smaller one is, well smaller, the larger variable can most surely contain the smaller one. Before I give an example, there is another error in the same line; there are multiple `Math.Min`s, one for a `decimal` and one for a `float`. The problem is that a `ulong` can be implicitly casted to either of these, meaning that you can do `float r = b //where b is a ulong` or `decimal r = b //where b is still a ulong` so, you must explicitly cast to specify that you want the decimal, or the float version of `Math.Min` Here is an example:

`jnd = (ulong)Math.Min(Math.Max(ind - (ulong)ipord / 2, 1), (decimal)(n - ipord));`

Have a nice day!!!

Comment: Thank you. So i must assign that inital value to every variable every time, in every method? Like inside methods i'm calling in my problem.

Comment: Yes you must cast it every time. After all, arithmetic operations are just methods in a class

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand what you meant until now, yes you must assign an initial value to every variable.